# Build a test node without exposing Alice account

Tags: substrate-node-template, apps

I need to build and run a substrate node in a such way that `polkadot.js.org/apps` will not display Alice, Bob etc at accounts page. I tried to remove all mentioning of Alice, Bob etc. from the rust code, but it didn't help: these accounts are still displayed, however have 0 balance.
I run my node with a command:

```
command: [
  "/usr/bin/node-template",
  "--dev",
  "--base-path", "/data",
  "--name", "ws-parachain-1",
  "--rpc-external",
  "--rpc-cors", "all"
]
```

Removing `--dev` from the command doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the [source code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/react-api/src/Api.tsx#L146) and this [issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/6752#issuecomment-1002637922), it seems explorer checks whether chain is:

1. local, if `ChainType::Local` or name contains `local`
2. dev, if `ChainType::Development` or name contains `dev`
3. test, if name contains `test`

before it populates the keyring with dev accounts.

If you really don't want to see dev accounts in the dev node, changing `ChainType` to `Live` in chain spec could solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped.